# layoutToolkit Accordion template?

Tags: wpf

I working on "layoutToolkit:Accordion" and wanna change AccordionItem's template (like a custom button with many visual graphic effects).But after that, AccordionItem lost Pre-template and became button.**How can I Change Template AccordionItem's?**

```
<layoutToolkit:AccordionItem  Header="like" >
                <layoutToolkit:AccordionItem.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </layoutToolkit:AccordionItem.Template>
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Button Content="1" Width="65" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <Button Content="2" Width="65" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Button Content="3" Width="65" Grid.Row="2"/>
                </Grid>
 </layoutToolkit:AccordionItem>
```

if U have any article about "layoutToolkit:Accordion" and how to use that, Send Link for me! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the answers that follow, i will post the default template. You will have to paste it together yourself tho, its too big to fit...
NOTE: the blue color is explicitly defined, just do a search for Blue and bind it properly.
Note 2: Its too long to fit in one answer, will post on 3

Namespaces:

```
xmlns:layoutPrimitivesToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives" 
xmlns:layoutToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls" 
xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=WPFToolkit" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<!--  layoutPrimitivesToolkit:AccordionButton  -->
<Style TargetType="layoutPrimitivesToolkit:AccordionButton">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="layoutPrimitivesToolkit:AccordionButton">
                <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="Transparent">
                    <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandDirectionStates">
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <vsm:VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="ExpandDown">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="icon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="icon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="cd0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <GridLength>Auto</GridLength>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="cd1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" To="-90" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="ExpandUp">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="icon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="icon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="cd0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="cd1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <GridLength>Auto</GridLength>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" To="90" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="ExpandLeft">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="icon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="icon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="rd0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <GridLength>Auto</GridLength>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="rd1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <TransformGroup>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                                                </TransformGroup>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" To="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="ExpandRight">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="icon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="icon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="rd0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="rd1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <GridLength>Auto</GridLength>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <TransformGroup>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                                </TransformGroup>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" To="180" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <vsm:VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.3" Storyboard.TargetName="icon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" To="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.3" Storyboard.TargetName="icon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" To="90" />
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="#FFBADDE9" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.5" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <vsm:VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00" />
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Checked" />
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <vsm:VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                                <vsm:VisualTransition From="MouseOver" GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.1" To="Normal" />
                                <vsm:VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.1" To="MouseOver" />
                                <vsm:VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.1" To="Pressed" />
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#222" />
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="#FFBADDE9" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.3" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF003366" />
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="#ff737573" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard />
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.385" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                    </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<!--  layoutPrimitivesToolkit:ExpandableContentControl  -->
<Style TargetType="layoutPrimitivesToolkit:ExpandableContentControl">
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
<Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow" />
<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="layoutPrimitivesToolkit:ExpandableContentControl">
      <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="0" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

```
<!--  layoutToolkit:Accordion  -->
<Style TargetType="layoutToolkit:Accordion">
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFEAEAEA" />
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
<Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
<Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow" />
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
<!-- Accordion expects a stackpanel to layout its children. -->
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="layoutToolkit:Accordion">
      <Grid x:Name="Root">
        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <!-- common states -->
          <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
          </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
          <!-- focus states -->
          <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
          </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
          <ScrollViewer IsTabStop="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="Transparent" Margin="0" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0">
            <ItemsPresenter />
          </ScrollViewer>
          </Border>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

```
<!--  layoutToolkit:AccordionItem  -->
<Style TargetType="layoutToolkit:AccordionItem">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFECECEC" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="layoutToolkit:AccordionItem">
                <!-- Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  -->
                <Grid Background="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                    <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <!-- CommonState -->
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <vsm:VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        <!-- FocusStates -->
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        <!-- ExpansionStates -->
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <vsm:VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                                <Storyboard x:Name="AccordionItemCollapsedStoryboard">
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(layoutPrimitivesToolkit:ExpandableContentControl.Percentage)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3" KeySpline="0.2,0,0,1" Value="0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.3" Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <Storyboard x:Name="AccordionItemExpandedStoryboard">
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(layoutPrimitivesToolkit:ExpandableContentControl.Percentage)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3" KeySpline="0.2,0,0,1" Value="1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        <!-- ExpansionStates -->
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="LockedStates">
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <vsm:VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Locked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unlocked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        <!-- ExpandDirectionStates-->
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandDirectionStates">
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <vsm:VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="ExpandDown">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="rd1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="cd0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="ExpandUp">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="rd0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="cd0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="ExpandLeft">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.ColumnSpan)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.ColumnSpan)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RowSpan)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RowSpan)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="rd0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="cd0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="ExpandRight">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.ColumnSpan)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.ColumnSpan)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RowSpan)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RowSpan)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="rd0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="cd1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                    </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="Background" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="1,1,1,1">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="rd0" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="rd1" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="cd0" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="cd1" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <layoutPrimitivesToolkit:AccordionButton Name="ExpanderButton" Style="{TemplateBinding AccordionButtonStyle}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}" IsTabStop="True" Grid.Row="0" Padding="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                            <layoutPrimitivesToolkit:ExpandableContentControl Name="ExpandSite" Grid.Row="1" IsTabStop="False" Percentage="0" RevealMode="{TemplateBinding ExpandDirection}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Style="{TemplateBinding ExpandableContentControlStyle}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<!--  layoutToolkit:TransitioningContentControl  -->
<Style TargetType="layoutToolkit:TransitioningContentControl">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Transition" Value="DefaultTransition" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="layoutToolkit:TransitioningContentControl">
                <Grid>
                    <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="PresentationStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="DefaultTransition">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentContentPresentationSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>

                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="UpTransition">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentContentPresentationSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentContentPresentationSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="30" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="-30" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>

                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="DownTransition">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentContentPresentationSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentContentPresentationSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-40" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="40" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>

                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                    </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PreviousContentPresentationSite" Content="{x:Null}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform />
                                        <SkewTransform />
                                        <RotateTransform />
                                        <TranslateTransform />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>

                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="CurrentContentPresentationSite" Content="{x:Null}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform />
                                        <SkewTransform />
                                        <RotateTransform />
                                        <TranslateTransform />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
                <Border x:Name="background" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="1,1,1,1">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="ExpandedBackground" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0" Background="#FFBADDE9" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="1,1,1,1" />
                            <Border Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="MouseOverBackground" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0" Background="#FFBDBDBD" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="1,1,1,1" />
                            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="cd0" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="cd1" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="rd0" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="rd1" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid Height="19" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="icon" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform />
                                            <SkewTransform />
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                            <TranslateTransform />
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <Path Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="arrow" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5">
                                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform />
                                                <SkewTransform />
                                                <RotateTransform />
                                                <TranslateTransform />
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                                    </Path>
                                </Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="6,6,6,0" x:Name="header" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Visibility="Collapsed" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```